# How to convert a standard normal to a d dimensional Gaussian with given covariance matrix?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

To convert standard normal z to a gaussian x with standard deviation s and mean m , we use the equation

```
x = z(s) + m
```

But how to do it in the following case:

We have the following,

```
Z : d dimensional standard normal
X : d dimensional gaussian with covariance matrix as S and mean as M
```

How to get X from Z using S and M?

Comment: *Hint*: You can take square-root of a positive (semi)definite matrix.

Comment: Think first about the simple case of one dimension, how would one do that. Then for $d$ dimensions see if the spectral decomposition of the covariance matrix proves to be helpful.

Comment: If $z$  components are independent, so are $x$ components.